# How to link to 400 "static pages" like [example.com/action/X.php] from 1 dynamic link?

Tags: links, meta-tags, dynamic, dreamweaver, static

I'm using Dreamweaver and running a flash gaming site with 400 games. I was updating things to add meta-data (for SEO). I wasn't sure weather to go with dynamic metadata or static metadata.

I have 1 home page that's supposed to link to 400 pages. `http://www.funkygames.co/`
However, I decided to go with static metadata (heard its better for SEO crawlers) .

I know how to dynamically generate 400 "dynamic" pages from 1 dynamic link. [see: `listing.php` below). I even know how to make them generate clean URLs.
but I don't know how to link to 400 "static" pages from 1 dynamic link.

Ex. The homepage should Link to static pages to below: (Static pages contain the unique metadata).

```
example.com/action/X.php
example.com/action/X2.php
example.com/action/X3.php
...
example.com/action/X400.php
```

Currently the homepage Links dynamically to:

```
listing.php?games_path=<?php echo $row_gamesList['games_path']; ?
>&category_id=<?php echo $row_gamesList['category_id']; ?>
```

(This was based on the "*game.swf*" and the "game-category" [used for "similar games"]).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution if anyone is interested. *shrugs*

```
/games/<?php echo $row_gamesList['game_file']; ?>?games_path=<?php echo $row_gamesList['games_path']; ?>&category_id=<?php echo $row_gamesList['category_id']; ?>
```

Added the database category "`game_file`" then linked it dynamically to the website. "`game_file`" contains all 400 static php files.

So now I just needed to add "`/games/`" or "`/action/`" before that. (Or whatever path your stuff will be in.)